# How to set constraints programatically?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I need to change the size of Constraint Layout Programatically but when I apply the new LayoutParams to the layout it removes the constraints that were there so I want to add them back programatically. The java code doesn't effect the layout.

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/timeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeFrom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="XX:XX"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inbetweenTimer"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/inbetweenTimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="--"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/timeFrom"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/timeTo"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timeTo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="XX:XX"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inbetweenTimer"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Java (the code is in recyclerView onBindViewHolder if that makes any difference)

```
    ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, newSize);

    ConstraintSet constraintSet = new ConstraintSet();
    constraintSet.clone(view.timeLayout);

    constraintSet.connect(view.timeFrom.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, view.timeBetween.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeFrom.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeFrom.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeFrom.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);

    constraintSet.connect(view.timeBetween.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, view.timeFrom.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeBetween.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeBetween.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeBetween.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, view.timeTo.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, 0);

    constraintSet.connect(view.timeTo.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, view.timeBetween.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeTo.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeTo.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, 0);
    constraintSet.connect(view.timeTo.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, view.timeLayout.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, 0);

    view.timeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    constraintSet.applyTo(view.timeLayout);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to add the constraints back to the layout. How are you changing the size of the _ConstraintLayout_? Can you show that code?

Comment: @Cheticamp it's in the first line of the java code - layout params, width is set to match_parent and the height to a new size. And once I apply those layout params the constraints stop working.

Answer (score 1):

All the constraint information is stored in [*ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams*](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) so, when you create a new instance of the layout params, you are wiping those constraints out. That is why you then need to recreate the constraints.

Instead, retrieve the current layout params from the *ConstraintLayout* and set the new size in these retrieved params:

```
ConstraintLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.timeLayout)
ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = layout.getLayoutParams();
lp.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
lp.height = newSize;
layout.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

The above code will preserve the constraints.

Comment: I tried this option before but I tried it again with your code and when I run it, it throws an error saying : `androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams` because the constraint layout is a child to that recyclerView. So I tried using one of the textViews instead but it either didn't display all the textviews or the constraint weren't working properly.

Comment: See corrected code. I was overspecifying the layout params.

Comment: The problem was in it's children.. since all of them were set to match_parent whenever I set a value to the main layout the first textView took over the whole view

Comment: You shouldn't be using `match_parent` with direct children of _ConstraintLayout_. Use `0dp` with the appropriate constraints instead.